# Only Update Specific Users Socket IO and Node JS

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to learn node JS and am currently attempting to extend this article.

http://www.gianlucaguarini.com/blog/push-notification-server-streaming-on-a-mysql-database/

I am having major issue because I am getting multiple updates in the SQL query.

I only want to send one socket update.

This issue is in the transactions loop I get multiple socket updates.

I have been struggling with this for over a month and can't seem to figure it out on my own (or with google searches)

Can someone please tell me how I can make this work so I only get one socket update per client.

What I would like to happen is when there is a change in one of the transactions that the two parties (buyer and seller) are the only ones that get the socket update.

How can I make this work? It is so close to what I want it do but I can't get over this last challenge.

Please help.

Thank you in advance.

```html
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>GAT UPDATER</title>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src = "http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="http://board.gameassettrading.com/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
         <script>
            var nodeuserid; 

            function getUserId() {
                var url = window.location.href;
                var user_id = url.replace('http://heartbeat.gameassettrading.com:4000/id/', '');
                return user_id; 
            }

            user_id = getUserId();

            $.cookie('useridcookie', user_id, { expires: 1 });

            var useridcookie = $.cookie("useridcookie");

            // Get Base Url for development between local and dev enviroment 
            function getBaseURL() {
                var url = location.href;  // entire url including querystring - also: window.location.href;
                var baseURL = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('/', 14));

                if (baseURL.indexOf('http://localhost') != -1) {
                    // Base Url for localhost
                    var url = location.href;  // window.location.href;
                    var pathname = location.pathname;  // window.location.pathname;
                    var index1 = url.indexOf(pathname);
                    var index2 = url.indexOf("/", index1 + 1);
                    var baseLocalUrl = url.substr(0, index2);

                    return baseLocalUrl + "/";
                }
                else {
                    // Root Url for domain name
                    return baseURL + "/";
                }

            }
            // set the base_url variable
            base_url = getBaseURL();

            document.domain = "transactionsserver.com"

            // create a new websocket
            var socket = io.connect('http://heartbeat.transactionsserver.com:4000');

            socket.on('connect',function() {
                    var data = {
                      url: window.location.href,
                    };
                    socket.emit('client-data', data);
            });
            // this is always open you have to filter out the data you want
            socket.on('notification', function (data) { 

                if(data.hasOwnProperty("data")) {
                    if(data.data[0]['seller_id'] != ''){
                    $('#StatusUpdate', window.parent.document).text( data.data[0]['seller_id']+ ':' + data.data[0]['seller_status'] +':'+ data.data[0]['buyer_id']+':'+ data.data[0]['buyer_status']).click();

                    }
                }

                window.parent.checkData(data,user_id);
                if(data.hasOwnProperty("changed_user_id")) {
                    $('#StatusUpdate', window.parent.document).text( data.changed_user_id+ ':' + data.changed_user_status +':'+ data.changed_user_id).click();
                }   
            });
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Server . js

```js
    var app = require("express")();
    var path = require('path');
    var mysql = require("mysql");
    var http = require('http').Server(app);
    var io = require("socket.io")(http);

    var sockets = {};

    var mysql = require('mysql'),
            connectionsArray = [],
            connection = mysql.createConnection({
                multipleStatements: true,
                host: 'localhost',
                user: '*****',
                password: '******',
                database: 'transactionsdb',
                port: 3306
            }),
            POLLING_INTERVAL = 1000,
            pollingTimer;

    // Add Redis For Comparing SQL Results againts Cache
    var redis = require('redis');
    var client = redis.createClient();
    var express = require('express');

    /* Creating POOL MySQL connection.*/
    var pool = mysql.createPool({
        connectionLimit: 100,
        host: 'localhost',
        user: '*****',
        password: '*****',
        database: 'transactionsdb',
        debug: false
    });

    var count = 0;
    var clients = [];

    function processAllTransactions(sellsreply) {

           pool.query('SELECT t.id,t.status,t.original_status, t.active, t.buyer_id, t.seller_id, t.seller_acked, t.seller_complete, t.buyer_complete, b.user_status as buyer_status,t.chat_ended, s.user_status as seller_status FROM transaction t LEFT JOIN sf_guard_user_profile s ON s.user_id = t.seller_id LEFT JOIN sf_guard_user_profile b ON b.user_id = t.buyer_id WHERE active = 1 LIMIT 1', [sellsreply], function (err, sells) {

               if (sells != '') {
                // attempt to stop the updates if it's not the the active transaction  
                client.get('active transaction id:'+sellsreply, function (err, active_transaction_id) {
                    passed_active_transaction_id = active_transaction_id;
                }); 

                // is there a trasnaction with status defined and transation id does not equal the active transaction id   
                if(sells[0].status !== undefined && sells[0].id !== passed_active_transaction_id )
                {
                    client.get('active transaction:'+sellsreply, function (err, data1) {

                        if(JSON.stringify(sells) != data1){
                            client.set('active transaction id:'+sellsreply,sells[0]["id"]);

                            client.set('active transaction:'+sellsreply,JSON.stringify(sells));

                            console.log(JSON.stringify(sells));

                            updateSockets({
                                data: sells // pass the database result
                            });
                        }   
                    });

                }
            } 
           });

    }

    // Method
    function getUserInfo(user_id, callback) {
        var query = connection.query('SELECT user_status from sf_guard_user_profile WHERE user_id = ' + connection.escape(user_id));
        query.on('result', function (row) {
            callback(null, row.user_status);
        });
    }

    var updateSockets = function (data) {
        // adding the time of the last update
        data.time = new Date();

        console.log('Pushing new data to the clients connected ( connections amount = %s ) - %s', connectionsArray.length , data.time);
        // sending new data to all the sockets connected
        connectionsArray.forEach(function (tmpSocket) {
            console.log(tmpSocket);
            tmpSocket.volatile.emit('notification', data);
        });
    };

    var pollingLoop = function () {

        var socket;
        for (var id in sockets) {
            socket = sockets[id];
            client.get("uuid:" + socket.id, function (err, useridreply) {
                processAllTransactions(useridreply);
            });
        }

        connection.query('SELECT * FROM sf_guard_user_profile; select * FROM transaction', function (err, result) {

            // error check
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                updateSockets(err);
                throw err;
            } else {

                // loop through the queries
                var element =
                        // compare the cache results againt the database query for users
                        result[0].forEach(function (element, index, array) {

                    client.get('logged_in:' + element.user_id, function (err, reply) {
                        if (reply === null) {
                            // console.log( element.user_id + ' is disconnected');
                        }
                        else {
                            // console.log(reply);
                        }
                    });

                    client.get("user:" + element.user_id, function (err, userreply) {
                        if (element.user_status != userreply) {
                            client.set('user:' + element.user_id, +element.user_status);
                            changed_users.push(element);

                                console.log(element.user_id + " is now set to: " + element.user_status);
                                updateSockets({
                                    changed_user_id: element.user_id,
                                    changed_user_status: element.user_status
                                });

                        }
                    });
                });

            }
            // loop on itself only if there are sockets still connected
            if (connectionsArray.length) {
                pollingTimer = setTimeout(pollingLoop, POLLING_INTERVAL);
                // reset changed users and changed transactions arrays
                changed_users = [];
                changed_transactions = [];
            } else {
                console.log('The server timer was stopped because there are no more socket connections on the app');
            }
        });
    };
    // count the connections array
    Array.prototype.contains = function (k, callback) {
        var self = this;
        return (function check(i) {
            if (i >= self.length) {
                return callback(false);
            }
            if (self[i] === k) {
                return callback(true);
            }
            return process.nextTick(check.bind(null, i + 1));
        }(0));
    };

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        // runs for every connection
        sockets[socket.id] = socket;

        socket.on('client-data', function (data) {
            // get the user id from the url that is passed onload
            var user_id = data.url.replace('http://servernameremoved.com:4000/id/', '');
            console.log('user id ' + user_id + ' is connected with session id ' + socket.id);
            client.set('uuid:' + socket.id, +user_id);
        });

        console.log('Number of connections:' + (connectionsArray.length));
        // starting the loop only if at least there is one user connected
       if (!connectionsArray.length) {
            pollingLoop();
      }

        socket.on('disconnect', function (socketIndex) {
            delete sockets[socket.id];
            client.get("uuid:" + socket.id, function (err, userreply) {
                console.log('user id ' + userreply + ' got redis disconnected');
            });
            socketIndex = connectionsArray.indexOf(socket);
                console.log('socketID = %s got disconnected', socketIndex);
            if (~socketIndex) {
                connectionsArray.splice(socketIndex, 1);
            }
        });
        connectionsArray.push(socket);
    });
    // express js route 
    app.get('/id/:id', function (req, res) {
        clients.contains(req.params.id, function (found) {
            if (found) {
                console.log("Found");
            } else {
                client.set('logged_in:' + req.params.id, +req.params.id + 'is logged in');
            }
        });
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client.html');
    });
    // build the server
    http.listen(4000, function () {
        console.log("Server Started");
    });
```

Here is the console log results

```js
Pushing new data to the clients connected ( connections amount = 2 ) - Sat May 30 2015 21:16:23 GMT-0700 (PDT)
30 2015 21:15:15 GMT-0700 (PDT)
user id 3 is connected with session id CRTtkRIl7ihQ2yaEAAAA
user id 2 is connected with session id wNG7XDcEDjhYKBEIAAAB
***********************************************
[{"id":1,"status":20,"original_status":15,"active":1,"buyer_id":2,"seller_id":1,"seller_acked":1,"seller_complete":0,"buyer_complete":1,"buyer_status":4,"chat_ended":"2015-05-31T03:58:40.000Z","seller_status":4}]
***********************************************
Pushing new data to the clients connected ( connections amount = 2 ) - Sat May 30 2015 21:16:23 GMT-0700 (PDT)
***********************************************
[{"id":1,"status":20,"original_status":15,"active":1,"buyer_id":2,"seller_id":1,"seller_acked":1,"seller_complete":0,"buyer_complete":1,"buyer_status":4,"chat_ended":"2015-05-31T03:58:40.000Z","seller_status":4}]
***********************************************
Pushing new data to the clients connected ( connections amount = 2 ) - Sat May 30 2015 21:16:23 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

Comment: If you're going to notify buyer and seller only of some server-side event, then you will need to know several things in your server: 1) For any given server-side event, which users are the buyer and seller for this event and 2) which webSocket belongs to that buyer and seller so you can send the info to just them.  Usually, there's some sort of user login that would likely be the unifying user identification (for both database and webSocket).